# C#: Type.GetType returns null for System.Collections.Generic.Stack

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I get null when I run

```
Type.GetType(
    "System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]")
```

And I get expected type when I run

```
Type.GetType(
    "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]")
```

What's wrong with the Stack type? Why GetType returns null in this case?

Comment: Why aren't you just using `typeof` to get the type that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Type.AssemblyQualifiedName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the `Type.FullName`.

```
Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
```

This correctly returns the equivalent to `typeof(Stack<Int32>)`

This takes into account that Stack does not live in the same assembly as int and List (mscorlib) but rather in System, which is the reason why it returns null without the proper assembly qualification.